# Appending a codepoint to an UTF8 std::string using icu4c

Tags: c++, unicode

My code is

```
void utf8_append(UChar32 cp, std::string& str) {
    size_t offset = str.size();
    str.resize(offset + U8_LENGTH(cp));
    auto ptr = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&str[0]);
    U8_APPEND_UNSAFE(ptr, offset, static_cast<uint32_t>(cp));
}
```

This works but seems ugly. Maybe I am overlooking a simpler approach?

Relevant documentation: https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/strings/utf-8.html and https://unicode-org.github.io/icu-docs/apidoc/released/icu4c/utf8_8h.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beauty is in the eye of the beholder. I say it is perfectly valid and correct code! The only thing you might get rid of is the `static_cast<uint32_t>`, as an `UChar32`, which is an alias for`int32_t`, will implicitly cast to `uint32_t` without warnings.
You could also use `append()` instead of `resize()`, avoiding the addition, and remove the temporary `ptr`, to finally get:

```
void utf8_append(UChar32 cp, std::string& str) {
    auto offset = str.size();
    str.append(U8_LENGTH(cp), {});
    U8_APPEND_UNSAFE(reinterpret_cast<uint8_t *>(&str[0]), offset, cp);
}
```

If you can use C++17, `str.data()` is slightly nicer than `&str[0]` in my opinion. Or you could write `&str.front()`.

Comment: "without warnings" Not with this project's warning settings. And no C++17, unfortunately.

Comment: Ah ok. Well if they are that strict then you're stuck with the `static_cast` of course. You could consider using `std::basic_string<uint8_t>` to get rid of both casts, but it will probably open up a can of worms elsewhere in your codebase.